# User current Locale inside entity OR trait

Tags: symfony, entities, symfony5

How can we access to current user local inside entity or Trait ?

```
namespace App\Entity;


class Activities
{
    use Translation;

   public $locale;

    public function __construct(**PUT User locale**)
    {
        $this->locale = **PUT User locale**
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Have you tried to access the user's data? Where did you store the locale?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because the locale is stored into the `Request` object which should'nt be accessed from an entity.

So if you really need that locale, you should pass it as an argument.

I suggest you to look around the [Doctrine extension documentation for translating entities](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/translatable.md).

You'll see that it's better than just passing the user locale each time.
In fact, it is using event listener to pass the locale to the `Translation` component.